# jQuery - set class "active" in li with cookie

Tags: jquery, class, cookies

I have some problems with setting class "active" in an `<li>` with a cookie.
I'm using this library https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
<UL CLASS="backchange">
    <LI CLASS='background_1' TITLE="White"></LI>
    <LI CLASS='background_2' TITLE="5% Black"></LI>
    <LI CLASS='background_3' TITLE="35% Black"></LI>
    <LI CLASS='background_4' TITLE="80% Black"></LI>
    <LI CLASS='background_5' TITLE="90% Black"></LI>
</UL>
<UL CLASS="patchange">
    <LI CLASS='patchange_1' TITLE="Diagonal line - transparent"></LI>
    <LI CLASS='patchange_2' TITLE="Diamond - transparent"></LI>
    <LI CLASS='patchange_3' TITLE="Dots - transparent"></LI>
    <LI CLASS='patchange_4' TITLE="Squares 1 - transparent"></LI>
    <LI CLASS='patchange_5' TITLE="Squares 2 - transparent"></LI>
    <LI CLASS='patchange_6' TITLE=""></LI>
    <LI CLASS='patchange_7' TITLE=""></LI>
    <LI CLASS='patchange_8' TITLE=""></LI>
    <LI CLASS='patchange_9' TITLE=""></LI>
    <LI CLASS='patchange_10' TITLE=""></LI>
</UL>
```

I used this jQuery, but it still isn't working. Is there another solution please?

Function for set cookie and class "active" in UL "backchange"

```
function setBackCookie() {
    BackCookieVal = $('.backchange li').hasClass('active') ? 'isActive' : 'notActive';
    $.cookie('BackCookieName', BackCookieVal, { path: '/' });    
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie('BackCookieName') == 'isActive') {
        $('.backchange li').addClass('active');    
    } else {
        $('.backchange li').removeClass('active');
    }
});

$(".backchange li").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    setBackCookie();
});
```

Function for set cookie and class "active" in UL "patchange"

```
function setPatCookie() {
    PatCookieVal = $('.patchange li').hasClass('active') ? 'isActive' : 'notActive';
    $.cookie('PatCookieName', PatCookieVal, { path: '/' });    
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie('PatCookieName') == 'isActive') {
        $('.patchange li').addClass('active');    
    } else {
        $('.patchange li').removeClass('active');
    }
});

$(".patchange li").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    setPatCookie();
});
```

Comment: you do not have any patchange class. So jquery cannot find any element with the predicades you want. ('.patchange li) isn't found anywhere.

Comment: What is actually not working? Not setting class either? or something else?

Comment: Sometimes all they LI have class "active". But I dont know why. Is there also another code?

Comment: @TelmoSilva: UL have class patchange

Comment: @skyndas `$('.patchange li').addClass('active');` means you're adding class `active` to all `li`s. You need to keep reference of the clicked `li` and same for `$('.backchange li').` And one more thing, place your `click` event codes within `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @skyndas OK, I see. But you are checking for the cookie state on document.ready wich means it will run only once when the page is loaded. As you are setting the cookie on an event, the code to toggle the class won't run again.

Comment: @thecodeparadox: Thanks. I understand.I'm going to test and learn :-)